# Where Do I Insert my DJI Windows SDK App Key

Tags: windows, dji-sdk

I created my app key as per the Readme, but I do not know where to add it.  I am also getting the errors below. I have not connected a drone yet because I do not own a compatible model.

[image]

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOZCY.png)

Comment: Hey Andrew, can you please be a little more specific in describing the app you created? What have you tried so far? Can you provide examples? Also, be sure to format your "Error Output" in a more readable format and adding more then 1 tag can help you get a little more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

The information to add the app key is in DJI's WSDK API documentation under: [method RegisterApp](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html#djisdkmanager_registerapp_inline).  You can find an example in DJI's Github WSDK Sample App here: [DJISDKManager](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Windows-SDK/blob/18c3ba70a1c7ee5a11c045081cda4ca449b09c02/docs/API%20Reference/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html)